# Запретить в цикле задавать одни и те же числа (сделать условие)

Tags: javascript

```
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // i=0; i<6
    this.blocks.push({
      colorIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * 16 + 1),
      id: Math.random().toString(16).slice(2),
    })
}
```

вот цикл, colorIndex должен грузить рандомные числа, но бывает что грузит одинаковые. каждое число это определенный цвет) не хочу что бы одинаковые грузило.
подскажите как изменить код что бы не грузил одинаковые.
кубиков всего 6шт

Comment: можно сделать массив допустимых значений. перемешать его. и взять в цикле первые 6, или сколько там вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так

```js
this.blocks = [];
var numbers = [];
for (var i; this.blocks.length < 6; i++) { // i=0; i<6
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16 + 1);
  if (!numbers.includes(randomNumber)) {
    numbers.push(randomNumber)
    this.blocks.push({
      colorIndex: randomNumber,
      id: Math.random().toString(16).slice(2),
    })
  }

}
console.log(this.blocks)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует использовать цикл while пока размер массива не будет равен 6. внутри добавляем проверку на существование такого индекса в массиве.

```
const blocks = [];
while (blocks.length <= 6) {
    const colorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 1;
    const isExists = blocks.find((block) => block.colorIndex === colorIndex);
    if (isExists) continue;
    blocks.push({
        id: Math.random().toString(16).slice(2),
        colorIndex
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

как дополение к моему комментарию, но метод шаффла тут плохой.

```js
var data = [...Array(16).keys()]
              .sort( () => Math.random() - 0.5)
              .slice(0,5) 
              .map( v => ({ 
                   colorIndex: v + 1, 
                   id: Math.random().toString(16).slice(2) }
                 ))
                     

console.log(data);
```

Comment: К тому же стоит еще добавить, что при таком перемешивании: `.sort(()=>Math.random() - 0.5)` не все результаты равновероятны.

Comment: @Yaant поэтому и написано, что перемешивание плохое